# SQL query with exists and count for many fields in subquery

Tags: abap

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM j_1gvl_ml AS jml
WHERE sptag IN @s_sptag AND
      bukrs = @p_bukrs AND
      werks IN @s_werks AND
      matnr IN @s_matnr AND
      tract IN @s_tract AND
      erdat IN @s_erdat AND
      repid = @p_repid AND
      EXISTS ( SELECT vrsio,whbcode,bukrs,belnr,buzei,
                      werks,locat,matnr,bwtar,orgn, COUNT( * )
                FROM j_1gvl_ml
                WHERE vrsio = jml~vrsio AND
                      sptag = jml~sptag AND
                      whbcode = jml~whbcode AND
                      bukrs = jml~bukrs AND
                      belnr = jml~belnr AND
                      buzei = jml~buzei AND
                      werks = jml~werks AND
                      locat = jml~locat AND
                      matnr = jml~matnr AND
                      bwtar = jml~bwtar AND
                      orgn = jml~orgn
                GROUP BY vrsio,whbcode,bukrs,belnr,buzei,
                      werks,locat,matnr,bwtar,orgn
                HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1  )
  INTO TABLE @itj_1gvl_ml.
```

There is an error that I cannot have more than 1 field in subquery.

I know that I can have 2 queries with for all entries. But I am looking if there is possible, to have in 1 query to have only the double, triple etc records.

Is this possible?

Comment: not clear what are you asking. Why mention FOR ALL ENTRIES here? IT has nothing to do with subqueries

Comment: This query with subquery is not working. It has an error that is "The SELECT clause for a subquery may only contain one column.". There is another solution with 2 separate queries. You are finding 1st the double records and then you display all fields with another using the FAE. I hope that is clear now what I mean.

Comment: What ABAP version do you use? (I'm thinking of `WITH` in 7.51)

Comment: ABAP version 7.50

Comment: @ekekakos Why do you specify columns in the subquery if you use EXISTS? Subquery may return data or not (result exists or not exists), fields here are meaningless. And that's why sap don't let you complicate things with field list of no relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `EXISTS` subquery is there to qualify which rows you want to select. It does not add rows or columns to the result set.

Reduce the list of columns in the `SELECT` clause of your sub query to any single one of the columns, or even a literal - such as `SELECT 1` - and you will get your duplicates:

```
SELECT *
  FROM j_1gvl_ml AS jml
  WHERE sptag IN @s_sptag AND
        bukrs = @p_bukrs AND
        werks IN @s_werks AND
        matnr IN @s_matnr AND
        tract IN @s_tract AND
        erdat IN @s_erdat AND
        repid = @p_repid AND
        EXISTS ( SELECT belnr
                  FROM j_1gvl_ml
                  WHERE vrsio = jml~vrsio AND
                        sptag = jml~sptag AND
                        whbcode = jml~whbcode AND
                        bukrs = jml~bukrs AND
                        belnr = jml~belnr AND
                        buzei = jml~buzei AND
                        werks = jml~werks AND
                        locat = jml~locat AND
                        matnr = jml~matnr AND
                        bwtar = jml~bwtar AND
                        orgn = jml~orgn
                  GROUP BY vrsio,whbcode,bukrs,belnr,buzei,
                        werks,locat,matnr,bwtar,orgn
                  HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1  )
    INTO TABLE @itj_1gvl_ml.
```

Comment: Thanks Florian, I didn't know this but I understand now.